# Count of Dictionary vs Count Key

Tags: powershell, dictionary

I wanted to count the number of parameters each Powershell cmdlet requires and noticed something strange:

```
$a = Get-Command Test-Connection
$a.Parameters.Count
```

I would expect a result of `13` but instead I got an object because the Parameters dictionary/hashtable actually contains a `'Count'` key (`$a.Parameters.'Count'`).

How does one differentiate between invoking the `Count` property (getter method) of the dictionary and accessing the `$a.'Count'` element?

Comment: I get 20 with `(Get-Command Test-Connection).Parameters.Keys.Count`

Comment: @AustinFrench Weird, I get 25 for the same command. Maybe a version difference? PSVersion 5.1.14393.103 on Win10 Enterprise

Comment: Yep, I'm on whatever is on this particular Win7 install.

Comment: Weird, today I also get an int instead of an object though I did upgrade to PS v.3 at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the type of the object. A little clumsy, but it would work something like:

```
$B = (Get-Command Test-Connection).Parameters
if ($B.GetType().Name -eq "Dictionary``2") { $B.Keys.Count}
else {$B.Count}
```

In all honesty though, I don't believe you should have to do this but it does give a work around.

Comment: What if some command also have `Keys` parameter?

Comment: You mean if the cmdlets parameters dictionary has a key named Count as well? 

ermagawd... Recursive checks I suppose? @PetSerAl

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *Recursive checks*, but suppose you have such function: `function f{param($Count, $Keys, $Unknow, $Number, $Of, $Parameters)}`. How did you get number of parameters for it?

Comment: I think it's academic at this point. (also I'm about 63.9% sure we are talking about the same thing) I tried your answer on the other screen and it gives the same answer. I also think that answer is a better approach. I'd vote to close this one as a dupe, but I can't